# the External database file pushed onto /data/data/database but can't cover the Original database file when run the app in the emulator

Tags: android, database, emulation

When I pushed the external database file for example a.db onto the device(emulator) ,so that to cover the original database file a.db in the path of /data/data/database/,and it worked..but when I run my app in the emulator,the a.db's data were missed.

And I test this in the phone,and the phone worked normal
I don't know why,can anyone help me
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*I think I have known why this happended. The database I pushed onto the device was created in windowXp,and now my system is Win7.*

Answer (score 0):

I think  I have known why this happended. The database I pushed onto the device was created in  windowXp,and now my system is Win7.